# Strange backslash in a Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm reading Learning Pearl (6e) and in the section about regexes I came across this particular example: `/\s(\[a-zA-Z]+),/`. What does the backslash before the open square bracket do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken at face value, the `\[` means that the regex as a whole is looking for a space character, a literal open square bracket (that's the `\[` part), the letters and dashes `a-zA-Z` in sequence followed by one or more close square brackets and a comma, where the material in square brackets is remembered. With a space in front the lines, it would match both these:

```
[a-zA-Z],
[a-zA-Z]]]]]]]]],
```

On the other hand, the backslash before the `[` is probably just a typo and should be deleted.  Then the regex looks for a space, followed by one or more alphabetic characters and a comma, capturing the 'word'.  With a space in front of the lines, it would match both these.

```
a,
aBcDe,
```

'Space' should be interpreted as 'white space as recognized by `\s`', meaning blank, tab, etc.

Comment: The face value interpretation wouldn't make sense with what they're explaining in that section so I'll go with typo.

Comment: I think typo is the more likely explanation.  You might consider checking the errata page at O'Reilly and seeing whether it is known, and if not, consider reporting it.